# Extracting rows from dataset matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I am generating a large dataset and would like to manipulate it afterwards.
Here is an example matrix of my dataset. The first 3 columns are data and the last two columns are indices of the runs (each row contains the results of a single run).

```
mat = {{0.2, 0.1, 0.01, 1, 1}, {0.1, -0.5, 0.4, 1, 
2}, {0.4, -1.1, -0.1, 2, 1}, {0.7, 1., 1., 2, 2}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 
3, 1}, {0.9, 1.1, 0.6, 3, 2}}; 
%//MatrixForm
```

[image]

I would like to:

a. extract row 3,4, and 5, based on the criteria that any element in the columns 1-3 is either < -1 or >1, or

b. extract rows based on the indices, e.g. row with 1,2 and row with 3,1 in the last two columns.

In either case, the result would be two new matrices, one with the remaining rows (not extracted) and another with the extracted rows.

The best I've been able to do is extract rows based on any element using `Select[]` and `MemberQ[]` which is not precise enough e.g. `Select[mat, MemberQ[#, 3] &]`

Many thanks.

Comment: You can make the select function as elaborate as you wish, so it seems that you need to write mathematically the criteria you are trying to state in words.  Once you do that, you can just use the same function with `GroupBy` to split the matrix into two parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic framework for your question is relatively simple.  First you need to select items from a list based on multiple criteria, and then you need to calculate which items from your list were not included.  In this case, the matrix formatting is irrelevant.

Your original code is simply a list of lists and then displayed a matrix:

```
mat = {{0.2, 0.1, 0.01, 1, 1}, {0.1, -0.5, 0.4, 1, 
    2}, {0.4, -1.1, -0.1, 2, 1}, {0.7, 1., 1., 2, 2}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 
    3, 1}, {0.9, 1.1, 0.6, 3, 2}};
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The key step is selecting the rows that meet your criteria.  Using `Select` you can link multiple criteria for each row by using `||` to indicate "OR".  (I am using `Abs` to streamline `<-1` or `>1`).

```
criteriamet = 
  Select[mat, Abs[#[[1]]] > 1 || Abs[#[[2]]] > 1 || Abs[#[[3]]] > 1 &];
criteriamet // MatrixForm
```

[image]

To put the remaining rows into their own matrix, you simply have to `Select` those who are not members of the list you just made.

```
criterianotmet = Select[mat, MemberQ[criteriamet, #] == False &];
criterianotmet // MatrixForm
```

[image]

There are certainly ways you can improve the code for clarity and efficiency, but this should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Excellent! That works splendidly. Thanks!